# javascript bind data of select2 input onchange event of another select2 input field rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Ok i have two select2 input fields and when i change the value of the first select2 input field, i want to be able to trigger the data that shud be in the 2nd select2 input field.

this is my two select2 fields in index.html.erb

```
  <%= f.input_field :lender_id, collection: Lender.all.pluck(:code, :id), class: 'form-control legal-service lender_field_code', prompt: 'Please Select Banker', disabled: (f.object.new_record? ? false : true ) %>

        <%= f.input_field :banker_id, collection: Banker.joins(:lenders).where("locked_at is null AND approved = true AND organizations.code = ?", params[:lender_id_code]).order(name: :asc), class: 'form-control legal-service lender_field_name ', prompt: 'Please Select', id: "banker_id" %>
```

the first select2 input field has a list of codes e.g ('AFG') and the 2nd select2 has a list of names 'Someone name'.

I already have the code to call the names only under the specific code but  i need my code my page to trigger the response. So when i select AFG only the names relating to AFG shud show up

in my javascript file i have the following code

```
$.get('/loan_applications/_lawyer_fields', function(data) { 
      $('.lender_field_name').html(data);
 });
```

Comment: Try this `$('.lender_field_code select').bind('change',function () {
       $(this).parents('.lender_field_code').find('.lender_field_name').text($(this).find('option: select').text());
    })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.lender_field_code select').bind('change',function () {    
    $(this).parents('.lender_field_code').find('.lender_field_name').text($(this).fi‌​nd('option: select').text()); 
})
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ArMq7/4/)